# Show editable Gridview when value is selected from dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a bulk edit gridview using Itemtemplate for each column. Label for non-edit mode, Textbox for edit mode. But this works only if the structure of gridview is known(Defining templates in asp).

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" Visible='<%# !(bool) IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" ControlStyle-CssClass="wide" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>'
                            runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is when the user selects a dropdown value, the sql query is fired and it returns result. And this result is shown in gridview. But the problem arises because the number of columns in the result for each selected value from dropdown may vary. And i want to make the gridview as editable(or read-only). This requires two templates to be defined for each column.

So i want to know how this can be done dynamically i.e defining templates depending on number of columns returned by sql.

Comment: The result as returned by the sql query, is it like infinite? I mean to say do you know the upper limit of the query, like how many columns will your gridview need to have?

Comment: No. it's not infinite. The no of columns that gridview need to have won't go beyond 20.

Comment: Then have a gridview with 20 columns, try to hide the unwanted columns when you have a particular number of selection from the sql query result.I know this is not very easy. You need to somehow get the number of columns and the order of the columns when you're binding the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you could trigger the query and following code with this event.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //insert code
    }
```

For the issue of different templates, I might suggest using two GridViews. I've done this where I have two separate sets of results. If they choose a dropdownItem, it hides GridView1 and shows GridView2 (while querying GridView2.SqlDataSource).

Now are you querying different SQL Tables based on dropdown? Or are they querying from the same place?

Comment: The querying is from many different tables. 
If I follow your approach. I would have to make around 15 Gridviews and toggle the visibility accordingly, which I think would be too cumbersome.

Comment: I get it. You never specified how many sets of results you would have. Are you combining many different tables into one table before querying? You could make a View in SQL first. Then, query that view and choose what columns you want and don't want. If it's one query per table, then I think setting a new datasource would be something to look into. Regardless, I'm not sure how organized it would be to have 15 different tables of results going to one gridview.